# (PowerBI) For each column in my table, how do I calculate the number of blank cells and cells with data?

Tags: powerbi

I have a large list of client data that I am interested in measuring the number of blanks and the number of cells with data (similar to using the counta and countblank functions in Excel). I'd like the data to be displayed in a table similar to the one pasted below.

Desired Output

[[image: Desired Output1]

Sample Data (first 4 rows)
[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Can you please show your sample data and expected output from them?

Comment: I edited the posting to include sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [COUNTBLANKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countblank-function-dax) DAX function.

Your DAX will be something like

```
Measure Name = COUNTBLANKS(tablename[columnname])
```

For counts of items that are not blank, then you need to [COUNTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/counta-function-dax) function, this will count all non empty cells

```
Measure Name = COUNTA(tablename[columnname])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. If I want to add multiple columns to make the chart that I've created, how would I adjust the DAX formula?